# can't import-module Hyper-V by powershell 4 in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I tried to use following cmd at Powershell 4 in Windows Server 2008 R2.
(Hyper-V has been running normally)

> import-module Hyper-V
>
> get-VM

*--> they are not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.*

> get-VM -servername "full server name" (from Windows 8)

*--> "Hyper-V" module is not installed in the remote server.*

Please shed your light on how I can control Hyper-V using PS 4.
Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this one but some modules are tied to Operating System. The link to Hyper-V Module suggests that it is available on Windows 2012, which would explain why you do not have it on the older Server OS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846767.aspx

Just installing newer version of PowerShell is not enough to get newer modules released with that version, you also need to be on the minimum OS they were released on.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Yes, we need WS2012 to use it.